# Handsontable: Getting HoT object in 'cells' function

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I'm upgrading from an old version of HandsOnTable and I'm getting some problems getting the HoT object in the cells function, eg.:

```
cells: function (row, col, prop) {
            var cellProperties = {};
            cellProperties.className = 'htMiddle htCenter';



            if (hot.getDataAtRowProp(row, "Team") == "Boston Celtics")
                console.log("Celtics");




            return cellProperties;
        }
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDataAtRowProp' of undefined

Shouldn't the HoT object be available by then?

What I'm trying to do is to check the value of a specific cell to know if I should change the renderer of this column.

http://jsfiddle.net/b5kagLzx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're having scoping issues. You have access to the `hot` object by doing `this.instance` so just change your code to

```
if (this.instance.getDataAtRowProp(row, "Team") == "Boston Celtics")
```

That should work (it does in your fiddle)